# in Django project. When annotate in views, getting error that item is not defined

Tags: python, django, filter

I know, that this subject has been mentioned few times, but I can't find a solution for my problem. So please accept my apologies for a repeat request.

I have a condition-based filter, that doesn't work for me.

here is my models.py file:

```
class Itemslist(models.Model):
    safety_stock = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=19, decimal_places=0)
    current_stock = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=0)

    def above_below_ss(self):
        ab = Decimal(self.current_stock-self.safety_stock)
        return round(ab,0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_n
```

Sorry, have to correct indentation, as it all belongs to one model class.

and here is what I have in views.py file:

```
from .models import *

def toorder(request):
    # toorder=Itemslist.objects.all
    sorted=Itemslist.objects.annotate(dontshow=above_below_ss()).exclude(dontshow__gt=0)
    context={ 'sorted': sorted }
    return render(request, 'toorder.html', context)
```

So here is a problem:
 when I'm using

```
toorder=Itemslist.objects.all
```

everything works, but when I'm trying this:

```
sorted=Itemslist.objects.annotate(dontshow=above_below_ss()).exclude(dontshow__gt=0)
```

it doesn't.

Interesting thing is that it used to work, but my code crashed without a copy, (during a back-up, which is funny enough),

And now it doesn't work.

I'm getting this message:

```
NameError at /toorder
name 'above_below_ss' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/toorder
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'above_below_ss' is not defined
Exception Location: /Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/mysite/itemlist/views.py in toorder, line 220
Python Executable:  /Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/mysite',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/artursjermolickis/projects/osmiocenter/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf']
```

If you need more pieces of code from me, please, just tell me what you need.

Really hope that you can help me here.

Here are additional comments to my question.

It is needed to filter the outcome by the mathematical function.

as an example I have posted `safety_stock`, and the solution, that is provided does work for that.

But as you have already mentioned, I need sort database, by a bit more complex function, so it's better to do it in models.py instead of doing it in vews.py that I can use it later. so the code, that I want to replace `safety_stock` with is:

```
def safe_stock(self):
        if self.safety_stock ==0:
            ss= (self.sales6mavgs()+self.stdev())*(self.lead_time+self.bookingterms)
        else:
            ss=Decimal(self.safety_stock)
        return Decimal(ss.quantize(Decimal('1'),rounding=ROUND_UP))
```

So from your suggestions, I did understand, that I have to implement `ExpressionWrapper`.

How to implement it with `ExpressionWrapper`

Question is now answered, please see details below.
I have Added a Manager to my models.py:

```
class ToOrderManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ToOrderManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
        dontshow=Round(ExpressionWrapper((F('current_stock')-F('safety_stock')), output_field=DecimalField()),0)
        ).annotate( leadtime=ExpressionWrapper(F('lead_time'), output_field=DecimalField())
        ).exclude(dontshow__gte=0).exclude(leadtime=0)
```

This lines have been added to my main model:

```
objects = models.Manager()
toorderobjects = ToOrderManager()
```

and my views.py looks like this now:

```
def toorder(request):
    sorted=Itemslist.toorderobjects.all()
    context={ 'sorted': sorted }
    return render(request, 'toorder.html', context)
```

However in my case, it looks like I will have to perform Raw queries in my case, due to complicated calculations.

Thank you very much for knowledge sharing!!!

Comment: The error message is very clear. You're using a function `above_below_ss` which hasn't been imported. Apart from that, what you're trying to do won't work - you can't  give a model method as an argument to a queryset annotation. You may need to use `ExpressionWrapper` here to do your math operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think this `dontshow=above_below_ss()` was workign because it's an instance method that means that you first fetched a single record and then called it `record.above_below_ss()`. 
You can instead write this method as a part of the annotation using [func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) and [expression wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper):

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    arity = 2
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from .models import Round

sorted=Itemslist.objects.annotate(dontshow=Round(ExpressionWrapper(F('current_stock') - F('safety_stock'), output_field=DecimalField()))).exclude(dontshow__gt=0)
```

If you want to reuse this you can move the query to [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#managers) and name it. Then, instead of each time writing long query, you'll simply use `Itemslist.objects.whatever_name_you_chose()`

Comment: And what error it raise? `above_below_ss` is not a variable but a model method and thus when you are using `self.field_name` it's actually a reference to the field of the specific record. To make this reusable to can move annotation code to model manager method.

Comment: Ok, the answer you have given does work in this case. but 1st I need it to be reusable, and 2nd, in my case `safety_stock` is something that I want to change for a mathematical explanation `ss= (self.sales6mavgs()+self.stdev())*(self.lead_time+self.bookingterms)`

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear I will add my comment to my question.

Comment: Ok, I extended answer about reusage. Next is that you'll not be able to use this kind of notation `self.sales6mavgs()+self.stdev()` in queries (I mean call model methods in queries). Just no way. If you need more complex expression then you'll need to define it with thous `F`, `ExpressionWrapper` and other `Avr` things in annotation. As a last resort you may consider using [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) queries with all logic developed in SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have applied a Manager for now, but I guess, will have to perform Raw queries, thank you very much for your help!!!